# AWS RDS automatic overwrite of instance from different instance's snapshot

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have 2 AWS RDS MySQL instances, one for devel environment and one for staging environment. And I would like make that every day a snapshot is taken from staging environment and copied over devel environment (overwriting any devel environment data). Is it possible to do so?

Comment: It's very simple.. You need to write a simple bash script to do so

1) Take a dump from staging
2) Source it to devel

OR

1) Create a snapshot from staging
2) Delete the existing devel
3) Launch a new devel from snapshot created from staging

Comment: @Vikash Regarding second option - launching new instance from snapshot -, is it possible for the new instance to have the same endpoint as old instance?

Comment: You can create a CNAME which will point to the new instance. But you need to scriptify that thing as well to point CNAME to new instance.